# wordpress article rendering with a strange "404" text below each one

Tags: wordpress

I have a very strange problem with a wordpress site I made for a friend of mine. I knew about the last WP bug fixed with version 4.2.2 , so I decided to update WP. As usual I made a backup with the plugin I usually use  (its name is duplicator), then upgraded and I decided to also uninstall some deactivated plugins and to install "all in one seo pack". After all this operations I noticed that below all articles there is a "404" text and I really can't understand where the hell it comes from. So I thought that I made something wrong and restored the backup to a new location to see how the site was looking at the moment I made the backup and also in the new install I can see this "404" text. Does anybody ever had a similar problem? I really can't understand what's causing this issue. Attached you will find a, example screenshot, but that identical situation happens for all articles (BUT NOT FOR PAGES).

Thank you for your help

[image: example of what's happening]

---

Just some minute after asking the question on SO, I found the problem: I decided to investigate the theme's pages in the editor and I found that the page "comments.php" was composed just from the text 404, as shown in the attached screenshot. Now the question is: how can it be possible? Could that mean that my site was hacked due to the wordpress bug resolved with the 4.2.2 version?

Comment: this is a link to a page, mybe someone inspecting the page could understand the problem http://www.naturalcalor.it/?p=764

Comment: Do you have a link to the site ?